# String Replacement Regex Condition

Tags: java, regex, string, replacewith

I have a text

> Hello everyone, my name is Ke-
>
> vin, I was born in Indonesia 20-
>
> 01-1990. Nice to meet you.

So how can I replace the text to

> Hello everyone, my name is Kevin, I was born in Indonesia 20-01-1990. Nice to meet you.

I've tried using `String string = string.replace("-\n" , "");`

> Hello everyone, my name is Kevin, I was born in Indonesia 2001-1990. Nice to meet you.

so how to put the different case in replace string? between alphabet before "-" and number.

Comment: [`-\n+`](https://regex101.com/r/yC4eF2/1)

Comment: Perhaps, `String string = string.replaceAll("-\n+(?!\\d)", "").replaceAll("-\n+" , "-").;`.

Comment: I think whatever API generated the source string is somehow broken: Adding a `-` should always be done so the second line should technically have ended with `20--`.

Comment: @manouti I don't think so. Hyphenation algorithms usually don't add a hyphen if one already exists in the text at around the point of breaking. The problem is that if this is the result of a hyphenation algorithm, it's not reversible for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the hyphen is preceded by a digit, you could use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to match the digit and the hyphen, and use `$1` as replacement:

```
(?:(\\d-)|-)
```

- Captures a digit followed by a hyphen
- Or matches a hyphen (not captured)

**Code**

```
String string = "Hello everyone, my name is Ke-\nvin, I was born in Indonesia 20-\n01-1990. Nice to meet you.";
String result = string.replaceAll("(?:(\\d-)|-)\\n+" , "$1");

System.out.println(result);
```

**Output**

```
Hello everyone, my name is Kevin, I was born in Indonesia 20-01-1990. Nice to meet you.
```

Answer (score -1):

String result = string.replaceAll("-","").replaceAll("\r\n", "");